Django ORM join on the same table twice using alias
We are using Django models. I'd need to add one more condition to join the same table twice with different conditions.
We have Account Model, Shop Model, and warehouse model.
Sample query:
select account_id, shop_id
from account as a1,
inner join shop as s1 on a1.id=s1.account_id,
inner join shop_to_warehouse_mapping as shop on s1.id = shop.id
inner join warehouse w1 on w1.id = shop.warehouse_id 
inner join warehouse w2 on w2.id = shop.warehouse_id
where w1.type='daily_life' and w2.type='produce'

We have shop to warehouse mappings, that's many to many.
I'd like to get the shop ids that are working with both warehouse 1 and 2.
In the Django models, we have the foreign key of warehouse on the shop to warehouse mapping model. How can I use filter method to represent this?
For some other reasons, we have to use the AccountModel.objects.filter(), if I add the third condition in a following filter call, it creates a second join on the shop model as well. But if I put it in the filter itself, it generates:
select account_id, shop_id
from account as a1,
inner join shop as s1 on a1.id=s1.account_id,
inner join shop_to_warehouse_mapping as shop on s1.id = shop.id
inner join warehouse w1 on w1.id = shop.warehouse_id 
inner join shop as s2 on a1.id=s2.account_id
inner join warehouse w2 on w2.id = s2.warehouse_id
where w1.type='daily_life' and w2.type='produce'

Any help's appreciated! (I'd love to write the query directly, but this query's complex having many other conditions already).
Thanks!

Please post your model code instead of trying to explain it in words.
